# How does OpenGL find the implementation to use on Windows?

Tags: windows, opengl

I have a Java program using OpenGL via JOGL, and there are some bugs that only appear on Windows that I'd like to debug. For this purpose, I tried setting up a spare computer with Windows, but encountered a strange problem when I went to debug my program:

When I run the program "normally" via Java Web Start, it works perfectly normally, but when I compiled the program and try to run it either via the command-line `java` launcher or via NetBeans (which I presume does the same thing), it appears to be using a different and very primitive OpenGL implementation that doesn't support programmable shading or anything.

When researching the problem, I've let myself understand that OpenGL programs running on Windows load `opengl32.dll`, which is apparently a common library that ships with Windows (correct me if I'm wrong) and which in turn loads the "real" OpenGL implementation and forwards OpenGL function calls to it. (It also appears to be somewhat of a misnomer, as it is in fact loaded in a 64-bit process at a base address clearly above 2<sup>32</sup>.)

Using Process Explorer, I see that, when I run the program under Java Web Start (where it works), it loads the library `ig4icd64.dll`, which I assume is the actual OpenGL implementation library for the Intel GPU driver; whereas when trying to run the program via `java.exe`, `opengl32.dll` is loaded, but `ig4icd64.dll` is never loaded, which appears to confirm my suspicion that it's using a different OpenGL implementation.

**So this leads to the main question, then:** How does `opengl32.dll` select the OpenGL implementation to use, and how can I influence this choice to ensure the correct implementation is loaded? What means are available to debug this? (And what is different between these two contexts that causes it to choose different implementations? In both cases, 64-bit Java is used, so there should be no confusion between 32- or 64-bit implementations.)

**Update:** I found [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff568203(v=vs.85).aspx) at Microsoft's site that claims that the OpenGL ICD is found by way of the `OpenGLDriverName` value in the `HKLM/System/CurrentControlSet/Control/Class/{Adapter GUID}/0000/` registry key. That value does correctly contain `ig4icd64.dll`, however, and perhaps more strangely, using Process Monitor to monitor the syscalls (if that's the correct Windows terminology) of the Java process reveals that it never attempts to access that key. I can't say I know if that means that the article is incorrect, or if I'm using Process Monitor incorrectly, or if it's something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When researching the problem, I've let myself understand that OpenGL programs running on Windows load opengl32.dll, which is apparently a common library that ships with Windows (correct me if I'm wrong) and which in turn loads the "real" OpenGL implementation and forwards OpenGL function calls to it.

Yes, this is exactly how it works. `opengl32.dll` acts as a conduit between the *Installable Client Driver* (ICD) and the programs using OpenGL.

> So this leads to the main question, then: How does opengl32.dll select the OpenGL implementation to use, and how can I influence this choice to ensure the correct implementation is loaded? What means are available to debug this?

It chooses based on the window class flags (that's not a Java class, but a set of settings for a window as part of the Windows API, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633577(v=vs.85).aspx for details), the window style flags the *pixel format* set for the window, the position of the window (which means which screen and graphics device it's on) and the context creation flags.

For example if you were to start it as a service then there's be no graphics device to create a window on at all. If you were to start it in a remote desktop session it would run on a headless, software rasterizer implementation.

I don't know the particular details in how the CLI `java` interpreter differs from WebStart. But IIRC you use `javaw` (note the extra `w`) for GUI programs.

---

> (It also appears to be somewhat of a misnomer, as it is in fact loaded in a 64-bit process at a base address clearly above 2^32.)

It's not just `opengl32.dll` but *all* Windows system DLLs that are named …32 even in a 64 bit environment, and they're even located in `\Windows\System32` to add to the confustion. For a very simple reason: Source code level backwards compatibility when compiling for 64 bits. If all the library names would have been changed to …64 then for compiling programs for a 64 bit environment *all* the string literals and references to the libraries would have to be renamed to …64.

If it makes you feel better about the naming, think of the …32 as a version designator, not an architecture thing: The Win32 API was developed in parallel for Windows 9x and Windows NT 3, so just in your mind let that …32 stand for *"API version created for Windows NT 3.2"*.

Comment: Thanks for the description, but I'm not sure it takes the question very far. Is there a way to debug the selection process, or perhaps alternatively a description detailed enough that I could follow it manually to reproduce the error? Does `opengl32.dll` perhaps support some kind of logging or somesuch?

Comment: Oh, and just for the record, using `javaw` instead of `java` made no difference.

Comment: @Dolda2000: Unfortunately the debugging capabilities of OpenGL are quite limited. OpenGL-4 did introduce a number of debugging facilities, but unfortunately these kick into action only long after context creation. However the problem you describe is highly unusual and reeks of an improper system installation. May I suggest that you look for any instances of `opengl32.dll` on your system. In a properly installed environment only two of them may exist: The one in `\Windows\System32` and the one in `\Windows\SysWoW64`.

Comment: "*reeks of an improper system installation*" -- That does sound weird, as the system is freshly installed just for this purpose. Then again, since that is so, I guess it doesn't hurt if I reinstall it to see if that helps. I'll try some stuff.

Comment: @Dolda2000: If this is a fresh install then nothing should be off, then. You did install the drivers downloaded from the GPU maker's website? A default, fresh Windows installation with drivers automatically installed by Windows lacks proper OpenGL support.

Comment: Well, I still haven't managed to figure out the root cause, but replacing Windows 10 with Windows 7 made it work for whatever reason. My theory is that Intel's drivers for older GPUs (this particular one is a Westmere Mobile i3) are buggy on Windows 10, because if one looks for it, they do in fact also display an error when installing (even though installation appears to work for the most part), so that's *probably* the reason. I even tried re-installing Windows 10 again from scratch to try again, but it seems to be reproducibly malfunctioning.

Comment: Thanks for making me realize it was a system configuration error. If not for that, I'd have continued to assume that it was something I was doing wrong.

Comment: "It chooses based on the window class flags the window style flags the pixel format set for the window, the position of the window and the context creation flags." How sure are you of this? Based on my testing it always just chooses the driver of the GPU connected to the primary display. That also matches what MSDN documents here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff568203(v=vs.85).aspx - if you know of a way around this to make it consider things like pixel format and window position then I would love some more details on how to do that.

Comment: @jalf: Choosing in this case does not mean, that there is a set of well documented rules which can be predictably used by the application to "select" which GPU to use. It's about repeatability, i.e. if you run the same program multiple times, with identical parameters, that the behaviour and output will repeatedly identical. Also if you have multiple GPUs of different capabilities, all GPUs that do not meet the requirements are excluded. Multiple GPU management is a weak point of OpenGL and was (among other things) one reason for the creation of Vulkan.

Comment: @datenwolf But have you actually verified that specifying different requirements will exclude GPU's which do not satisfy them? In my testing, if I have two GPUs, one on my primary screen which does not support a specific pixel format, and another GPU which does support it, and I request that pixel format with ChoosePixelFormat, then Windows *still* loads the first GPU's driver. In my testing (and just returns a different pixel format than I requested). As far as I can tell, Windows *always* uses the GPU attached to your primary display. Have you *verified* that it ever does anything else?

Comment: I have also tested with window position. No matter which screen I position my window on, it *always* uses the GPU behind the primary display. So if you can show me a scenario in which Windows considers *anything* at all other than "which is my primary GPU", I would be very interested in seeing that